# Incluir direto no input select - MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Eu tenho este campo select, onde carrego os dados do banco:

```
<label asp-for="CategoriaID" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <select asp-for="CategoriaID" asp-items="@Model.CountryList" class="form-control"></select>
    <span asp-validation-for="CategoriaID" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Porém surgiu a necessidade do usuário poder incluir direto neste campo, seria possível ? Pois ao verificar no select, pode não existir a categoria, assim ele poderia digitar, e incluiria no banco.

Comment: Acredito que seja mais uma decisão de design que de programação. Você pode ter um botão "Incluir categorias", ou pode ter uma opção "Outro" em seu Select... a solução vai depender de como pretende abordar a questão.

Comment: @BrunoSoares eu gostaria que ele pudesse ter a opção de digitar no select, ao clicar no enter, perguntar se ele gostaria de incluir no banco, e então incluir.

Comment: Entendi, no próprio select não é possível nativamente, mas há componentes bootstrap ou jquery que podem lhe ajudar. Uma solução mais simples seria realmente uma opção "Outro", que quando selecionado exibe um textbox para digitação.

Comment: @BrunoSoares pensei em fazer isso então através de um modal, e carregar novamente o select sem refresh na página.

Comment: É uma ótima saída, caso tenha conhecimento de ajax necessário, recomendo =)

Comment: Fiz dessa forma, e com ajax, obrigado.